# using CTE in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, common-table-expression

I want to have CTE in subquery. the code is like below:

```
 select object_id, 
 change_time,
 old_value,
 new_value   ,
 DENSE_RANK() over ( partition by object_id order by change_time) "seq_no"
from (
;with cte
as (
select * from #tmpfup
union 
select distinct fup.object_id, datee.change_time, datee.old_value, 
datee.new_value
from #tmpfup fup, #tmpdate datee
)
select * from cte 
)
```

I don't know if this query is possible or not but I tried it in SQL Server and got errors can anyone help me?

Comment: CTE's go at the **start** of a statement. Also, a statement terminator (`;`) goes at the end of a statement, that's why it's called a terminator, not in the middle (or as some seem to believe, at the start of a `WITH`/`MERGE` clause...).

Comment: @Lamu Just a note: in general, the open source databases support CTEs in the middle of a statement: PostgreSQL, MariaDB, and MySQL. The commercial ones do not: Oracle, DB2, and SQL Server. Oracle do support them as Table Expressions, just not as Common Table Expressions.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, CTEs go before the first `SELECT`:

```
with cte as (
      select * from #tmpfup
      union 
      select distinct fup.object_id, datee.change_time, datee.old_value, datee.new_value
      from #tmpfup fup cross join
           #tmpdate datee
     )
select object_id, change_time,old_value, new_value   ,
       DENSE_RANK() over ( partition by object_id order by change_time) as seq_no
from cte;
```

Note that you also need a table alias in the outer `from` clause (but I removed that subquery).

Also, some database *do* support CTEs with subqueries.  SQL Server is not one of them.

Comment: Surely the `from (select * from cte) cte` is a little redundant?

Comment: In general, the open source databases support them: PostgreSQL, MariaDB, and MySQL. The commercial ones do not: Oracle, DB2, and SQL Server. Oracle do support them as Table Expressions, just not as Common Table Expressions.